# Stop event bubbling to Chrome browser for alt-keypress

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events, event-bubbling

(Encountered while writing [this script](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/blob/master/StackExchange/MathJaxButtons.user.js) )

Relevant code:

```
window.keyPressEventLambda=function(key,callback){ //just a lambda function wrapper so I can generate handlers on the fly
return function (zEvent) {
        if (zEvent.altKey  && ( zEvent.which == key.charCodeAt(0)||zEvent.which == key.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0))) {
            callback(this.id);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
}
}
```

Use case:

```
$("textarea").live("keydown",keyPressEventLambda("C",function(id){/*blah blah blah */})
```

So, if I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, the callback function runs itself.

Now, due to the `return false;`, bubbling is suppressed and everything is handy-dandy within the page itself.

But, Chrome (20.0.1128.0 or 19.0.1084.41 on Windows), still captures the alt key as a Chrome browser shortcut, and, since no shortcut actually exists for <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, it fails and makes an annoying "ping" sound.

It works fine for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-shortcuts, but I don't want to use these since most of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-shortcuts are taken.

Is there any way to prevent the browser from getting angry at my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known Chrome-issue. See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=105500